# Hibernate criteria filter on foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate, filter, criteria, alias

Can we create deep alias for foreign key table using criteria?
For example if I have three table `A`, `B` and `C` where `C` is foreign key table of `B` and `B` is foreign key table of `A`.
I want to apply filter like the following statement:

```
session.createCriteria(A.class).createAlias("A.bObjectField", "alias1")
       .createAlias("alias1.cObjectField", "alias2")
       .add(Restrictions.eq("alias2.id", 1));
```

Can I filter the table `C` from `A` using criteria?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's no problem as long as you have modelled the foreign keys in your mappings.